# Scope troubles with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, scope

I've been running into difficulty when trying to compile this simple program in CodeBlocks today:

```
// Include standard headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW. Always include it before gl.h and glfw.h, since it's a bit magic.
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GL/glfw.h>

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

int main(){
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4); // 4x antialiasing
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // We want OpenGL 3.3
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);    
    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental=true; // Needed in core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle( "Tutorial 01" );

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

    do{
        // Draw nothing, see you in tutorial 2 !

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
    glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );
}
```

This code is from the tutorial http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/

I think the problem may have been caused by the fact that I couldn't get CMake to work properly, so I just copied the dependencies into the CodeBlocks directory.

The errors all refer to the scope of glfw...

```
In function 'int main()':
|23|error: 'GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES' was not declared in this scope
|24|error: 'GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR' was not declared in this scope
|25|error: 'GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR' was not declared in this scope
|26|error: 'GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE' was not declared in this scope
|26|error: 'GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Which version of GLFW are you using?

Comment: Why is `glfw.h` in the same system directory as `GL.h`? They are not at all related, and should be in separate locations. The same goes for GLEW.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: That's how the library is packaged. Its header is put inside a `GL` subdirectory, inside the library's directory.

Comment: @sftrabbit API version: 2.5

Comment: @legends2k: Then do not use <GL/glfw.h>, that is for system headers. You want "GL/glfw.h"

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you are reading use Glfw 2, you probably downloaded GLFW 3.0
Downgrade glfw or follow this guide for version migration:
http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/moving.html